# How to input open intervals

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I want to write open and half-open intervals using the following notation:

```
]a, b[
]a, b]
]-∞, b]
```

When writing them just like that in the LaTeX source, the spacing doesn't come out right. For example, for this equation:

```
 \(X = ]-\frac{π}{2}, +\frac{π}{2}[\)
```

the minus sign is typeset as a binary operator. I can solve this by surrounding the whole value in braces, but then the spacing around the equal sign is still not correct. For other combinations of intervals and operators, different spacing inconsistencies arise.

What is the correct and easy  way to input intervals in order to avoid having to take care of this at all?

Comment: `\(X = \left]-\frac{π}{2}, +\frac{π}{2}\right[\)` ?

Comment: ...or you could use wrap the interval in `{}`: `\(X = ]{-\frac{π}{2}, +\frac{π}{2}}[\)`. However, this would work best when the contents is not in displaymath mode.

Comment: @Martin and Werner: thanks for your responses. Please post them as answers so I can accept them.

Comment: take a look at `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`.  (i haven't time to write a more complete answer.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `\left]` and `\right[` then the brackets are taken as delimiters (and also get resized accordantly to the content):

```
\(X = \left]-\frac{π}{2}, +\frac{π}{2}\right[\)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I had overlooked this obvious solution, since I had always used \left and \right only for the resizing behavior. Thanks!

Comment: Knuth speaks about "perverse mathematicians" that use this notation. :) In case the resizing is not needed, it's better to say `\mathopen]a^2,b^2\mathclose[` (this is indeed a case where resizing is bad).

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I didn't know `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` before. I'm not a mathematician at all, neither a perverse one or otherwise :-)

Comment: @egreg, @Martin: Then all French mathematicians are perverse ;-) More seriously, the best for intervals is a macro which takes care of everything (and allows to choose between the resizing and non-resizing version). Since with `\left`/`\right` you can have spacing problems (e.g. in `\left]a,b\right[.` the dot is too far away) due to the fact that it makes what it encloses of type `\mathinner` instead of `\mathopen` to the left and `\mathclose` to the right, the best when you want the resizing behavior is to use `\mathopen{}\mathclose{\left]...\right[}`.

Comment: @Philippe: I'm not fond of "automatic" `\left` and `\right`; in the case of the interval (sqrt(2),2), for example, or (a^2,b^2), using `\left` and `\right` produces too big delimiters. That all French mathematician are perverse is well known. :)

Comment: @egreg: yes, but in display mode, you might need to use `\left`/`\right` and it's still important to have correct spacing.

Comment: @egreg: I like that ``\mathopen`` and ``\mathclose`` are more orthogonal (you don't get resizing for free). I'm not too fond of ``\left`` and ``\right`` either, I usually use ``\bigl``- and ``\bigr``-like delimiters.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet - I assume you're familiar with the following quote from Johann Wolfgang Goethe: "Mathematicians are like the French: You talk to them, they'll translate into their own language, and immediately it's something entirely different." :-)

Answer (score 19):

While I'm a little late to the party, here goes for a slightly more *concise* solution:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\INTERVALINNARDS}{ m m }{
    #1 {,} #2
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\interval}{ s m >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m m o }{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \left#2 \INTERVALINNARDS #3 \right#4
    }{
        \IfValueTF{#5}{
            #5{#2} \INTERVALINNARDS #3 #5{#4}
        }{
            #2 \INTERVALINNARDS #3 #4
        }
    }
}
```

which allows you to do:

```
\begin{align*}
    \interval[{a,b}] &&           && \\
    \interval[{a,b}) && \text{or} && \interval[{a,b}[ \\
    \interval({a,b}] && \text{or} && \interval]{a,b}] \\
    \interval({a,b}) && \text{or} && \interval]{a,b}[
\end{align*}
```

to obtain something like:
[image: Interval open / closed example]

Or to use manual or automatic resizing:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \interval[{a,\infty})[\Bigg] \quad \text{or} \quad
        \interval*[{-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}}]
\end{equation*}
```

to obtain:

[image]

Edit:
Added the changes suggested by egreg (this was my answer, was just unregistered at the time).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is nice; I'd exchange the conditions and use `*` to get the `\left`-`\right` version: I don't like this kind of automation that can give unwanted spacing; also macros defined with `\DeclarePairedDelimiters` (`mathtools` package) use the *-version for the "automatic size" version. It wouldn't be difficult to add an optional argument for accommodating `\big` and friends in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 12):

The `interval` package takes care of the spacing and the scaling of the brackets.

*Edit*. An example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{interval}

\begin{document}

    \[ \interval[scaled]{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}\qquad\interval[scaled=\bigg]{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add an example?

Comment: @shuhalo: Sorry, I've just discovered your question. I've added  an example. Note such command can also be defined with  `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`.

Answer (score 4):

At least two options exist.

---

**Option 1**: `\(X = \left]-\frac{π}{2}, +\frac{π}{2}\right[\)`

This works well, even in displaymath mode (`\[...\]`) since the delimiters are extensible. However, in inline math mode you'll notice the braces may expand more than your liking. For that, use **Option 2**.

---

**Option 2**: Wrap the interval in `{}`: `\(X = ]{-\frac{π}{2}, +\frac{π}{2}}[\)`

---

Comment: The latter option has the advantage that it doesn't clutter the markup too much. I may end up prefering it for simple cases. Thanks!

Comment: The latter option has the drawback, that it does not give proper spacing with `\in`, e.g. `x\in]{-2},2[`

Comment: @PhilippImhof: Then use `$x \in {}]{-2},2[$`.

Comment: Thanks. I rather stick to `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`. It's more typing, but its logic is straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a macro which takes care of the spacing and allows you to choose between a resizable version (when followed by a star, for use in display) and a fixed-size version (without a star, for use in text). You have four macros `\intervalcc`, `\intervaloo`, `\intervaloc` and `\intervalco` for the various types of intervals (`o` is for open and `c` for closed):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\genericinterval}[2]{%
  \@ifstar{\genericinterval@star{#1}{#2}}{\genericinterval@nostar{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\genericinterval@star}[4]{\mathopen{}\mathclose{\left#1#3,#4\right#2}}
\newcommand{\genericinterval@nostar}[4]{\mathopen{#1}#3,#4\mathclose{#2}}
\newcommand{\intervalcc}{\genericinterval[]}
\newcommand{\intervaloo}{\genericinterval][}
\newcommand{\intervaloc}{\genericinterval]]}
\newcommand{\intervalco}{\genericinterval[[}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$I = \intervalcc{-a^2}{b^2} \cap \intervalcc{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$

\[I = \intervalcc{-a^2}{b^2} \cap \intervalcc*{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.\]

$I = \intervaloo{-a^2}{b^2} \cap \intervaloo{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$

\[I = \intervaloo{-a^2}{b^2} \cap \intervaloo*{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.\]

$I = \intervaloc{-a^2}{b^2} \cap \intervaloc{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$

\[I = \intervaloc{-a^2}{b^2} \cap \intervaloc*{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.\]

$I = \intervalco{-a^2}{b^2} \cap \intervalco{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$

\[I = \intervalco{-a^2}{b^2} \cap \intervalco*{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.\]

\[\intervaloo*{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}^2.\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't like how the markup ends up looking like. Too much clutter! Thanks anyway, I always learn something new when looking at someone else's macros :)

Comment: @Roberto: if your TeX editor uses different colors to highlight differently nested braces, the formulas remain very legible. The reason these macro are useful is if you need to do things more complicated with, e.g., the interval separator (I use `\mathclose{}\mathpunct{};` for a correct spacing of the semi-colon in French and these macros allow me not to have to type it each time).