# Delimiters as math symbols (and not delimiters)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, delimiters

I am currently using delimiters (brackets, [ and ], to be precise) as symbols in math equations. Of course, the compilator considers the brackets as delimiters, and the spacing is thus not very pleasant.
See for example

```
$a=]_ib$
```

against a more aesthetically pleasing (but very ad-hoc)

```
$a=\ ]_i\,b$
```

Is there a way to define a command that will print [ and ] as regular symbols (and so add spacing accordingly)?

Before anyones points me to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27116/using-and-as-math-symbols-not-delimiters), the correct answer in this case was to reverse the order of delimiters. I would like to define them so they are not delimiters at all. I still use regular brackets as delimiters sometimes, so defining a new command would be better (symbols brackets always have an index).

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A math symbol can be turned into an ordinary symbol by just enclosing it in braces. So

```
$a = {]}_{i}b$
```

should do what you want. Perhaps you should define your own command:

```
\newcommand{\orbrack}{{]}}
```

and type

```
$a = \orbrack_{i}b$
```