# French notation for intervals ]x,y[

Tags: math-mode, spacing, brackets

I use French notation for intervals, like `]x,y[`.
But the brackets behave funny --- they try to surround wrong thing, like

```
] x,y [∪] a,b [
```

Writing `\left]x,y\right[\cup\left]a,b\right[` solves the problem in most cases. But I want these brackets to have the same size, but they become larger on something like `]a,B^c[`.

P.S. My question is closely related  to ["How to input open intervals"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23640/), but not the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `\mathopen]x,y\mathclose[`

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: Consider using [`mleftright`](//ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) and then `\mleft] x, y \mright[`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wouldn't it be better to use `\mathopen]x,y\mathclose[` instead of `\mathopen{]}x,y\mathclose{[}`? Suppose you want to write ]x,y[²: If you use `\mathopen{]}x,y\mathclose{[}^2` the vertical positioning of the superscript "²" is bad. (Note that the braces aren't argument delimiters here because `\mathclose` is a TeX primitive. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110220/227621.)

Comment: @user227621 er, yes, done, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The `interval` package by Lars Madsen has been designed to take care of this kind of problem (and some others):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{interval}
\begin{document}
\[
    \interval[open]{x}{y} \cup \interval[open]{a}{b}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

See its [documentation](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/interval/interval.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this clean package!

Answer (score 6):

If you have many of these intervals, you may want to create a dedicated macro called, say, `\frint` (short for "French-notation interval"...), as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\DeclarePairedDelimiter" macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\frint}{]}{[}

\begin{document}
$\frint{x,y}\cup\frint{a,b}$
%% same output as '$\mathopen{]}x,y\mathclose{[} \cup \mathopen{]}a,b\mathclose{[}$'
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then, write `\frint*` to auto-size the "fences", and write `\frint[\big]`, `\frint[\Big]`, `\frint[\bigg]`, or `\frint[\Bigg]` to enlarge the fences to a specific, fixed size.

Answer (score 4):

Time ago, I created my own french notation intervals with several commands depending on type of interval (they added some unnecessary extra space). Now I implemented the `\mathopen{]}` and `\mathclose{[}` (as in David Carlisle answer). I use (in preamble)

```
\newcommand{\cord}{\mathopen{]}}
\newcommand{\cori}{\mathclose{[}}
\newcommand{\intsai}[2]{\cord #1,#2\cord}
\newcommand{\intsad}[2]{\cori #1,#2\cori}
\newcommand{\intc}[2]{\cori #1,#2\cord}
\newcommand{\inta}[2]{\cord #1,#2\cori}
```

Here is an example of application

[image]

```
\[
\arraycolsep=10pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{array}{cc}
\textbf{bounded}    &   \textbf{unbounded}  \\
\inta{x}{y}         &   \inta{-\infty}{y}   \\
\intc{x}{y}         &   \intsai{-\infty}{y} \\
\intsad{x}{y}       &   \inta{x}{+\infty}   \\   
\intsai{x}{y}       &   \intsad{x}{+\infty} \\
\end{array}
\]
\qquad
\[\inta{x}{y}\cup\inta{a}{b}\]
```

Comment: this is still using a mathclose node on the left and a mathopen on the right so the extra fixed spacing will not always be right depending on the context and the spacing that the mathopen and mathclose nodes add.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that is true. Actually as you say, the fixed space make the intervals look weird (e.g. infinite negative intervals above).  What would be a good practice to avoid that, preserving some "good looking" space in custom commands?