# Add space before \to iff preceding "["

Tags: spacing, xspace

How can I automatically have a space added before `\to` iff there is a `[` before it?

It's just that

```
$f\colon]a;b[\to[c;d]$
```

looks awfully bad...

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to print.... It is awful anyway for me (not because of distances). May be a draw or something else would help. I can not imagine what you are trying to have as your output

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have been more explicit. I want the definition of `\to` to include

    $[\to$

being automatically printed as

    $[~\to$

Comment: What about a command like : `\newcommand\myto{[~\to}` or similar? (it has to be inside math or to be defined as \newcommand\myto{$[~\to$} to be in math mode by itself) (Yiu can redefine it to using `\def` or `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`)

Comment: I still want my code to be `[\to` due to readability....

Comment: Do you also want to be able to use "\to" without "[" before of it?

Comment: Sure. There should not be a space in cases like `]\to`

Comment: `f\colon\mathopen]a;b\mathclose[\to[c;d]`

Comment: @egreg so slow:-)

Comment: You should consider the `interval` package.

Answer (score 4):

`]` is a mathclose by default but you need it to be a mathopen:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$f\colon]a;b[\to[c;d]$

$f\colon\mathopen]a;b\mathclose[\to[c;d]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `f\colon\mathopen]a;b\mathclose[\to[c;d]` instead of `f\colon\mathopen{]}a;b\mathclose{[}\to[c;d]`? (The same thing as in [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407077/227621) to another question)

Comment: @user227621 you searching the whole site for \mathopen answers?? :-)