# Overspacing for a text

Tags: math-mode, package-writing

In the book I'm writing there are some parts with math-mode spaces and math-mode inline spaces that are too excessive for me. The first and the second image that I am reporting are taken directly from the textbook that makes the idea of excessive spacing (see some annotates red arrows).

### Real first image taken from my book

[image]

### Real second image taken from my book

[image]

Here there is a compilable MWE that reproduces the similar problem. I was asking myself if the spacing is normal or if there is something that I should fix either in the text or in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm,
            left=3.2cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=10pt,
            a4paper]{geometry}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\showhyphens{matematica}
\begin{document}
\noindent Ovviamente deve essere $1-c^2>0$ e cioè $|c|<1$ perchè sia lecita la relazione \ldots. La costante arbitraria $c$ può avere segno qualsiasi; deve aversi cioè $\forall x\in ]a,b[, \,y'(x)=c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ oppure $y'(x)=-c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$. Potrebbe essere $c=0$ compatibile solo con $y(a) = y(b)$, segmento parallelo all'asse $x$. Se $c\ne 0$, allora anche $c/\sqrt{1-c^2}\ne 0$, e dovendo $y'$ essere continua non può accadere che per certi $x\in ]a, b[$ valga il segno $+$ e per altri il segno $-$ (altrimenti $y'$ salterebbe senza assumere i valori intermedi fra $c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ e $-c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$). Deve quindi valere $y'(x)=c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ per ogni $x\in]a,b[$, oppure $y'(x)=-c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ sempre per ogni $x\in]a,b[$: dato che $c$ è, come detto prima, costante di integrazione indeterminata, non si perde nulla a scrivere $y'(x)=c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ qualunque sia $c$. Posto 
$m=c/\sqrt{1-c^2}\in \mathbb{R}$, ed essendo $c$ variabile in $]-1,1[$ allora $m=c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ assumerà tutti i valori reali. La soluzione generale dell'equazione di Eulero è $y(x)=mx+k$; dovendo essere $y(a)=\alpha$ ed $y(b)=\beta$ si ricava $ma+k=\alpha$ ed $mb+k=\beta$, da cui $m=(\beta-\alpha)/(b-a)$ e $k=\alpha-a(\beta-\alpha)/(b-a)$. Ma ci si poteva fermare una volta scoperto che $y'$ deve essere costante: questo prova che le uniche soluzioni sono segmenti di rette come il percorso più breve, e ce n'è uno solo che passa per due punti dati $(a,\alpha)$ e $(b,\beta)$, come ben sappiamo. La funzione integranda non dipende esplicitamente da $x$ quindi il funzionale è del tipo
\[\mathscr{F}(y)=\int_{a}^{b}f(y,y')\,dx\]
In questo caso l'equazione di Eulero-Lagrange  
\[\frac d{dx} \frac{\partial f(y,y')}{\partial y'}-\frac{\partial f(y,y')}{\partial y}=0\]
Se poi $y$ è di classe $\mathcal{C}^2$ in $[a,b]$ diventa, dalla \eqref{elfd2}, per il teorema di derivazione delle funzioni composte,
\begin{equation}\label{edex}
f_{y}(y,y')-f_{y'y}(y,y')y'-f_{y'y'}(y,y')y''=0
\end{equation}
Moltiplicando la \eqref{edex} per $y'$, otteniamo l'equazione di Eulero-Lagrange è
\[\dfrac d{dx}(f-y'\,f_{y'})=0.\]
Infatti si ha
\[\begin{split}\dfrac d{dx}(f-y'\,f_{y'})&=f_y\,y'+f_{y'}\,y''-y''\,f_{y'}-(y')^2\,f_{yy'}-y'\,y''\,f_{y'y'}=\\
&=y'(f_y-y'\,f_{yy'}-y''f_{y'y'})=y'\cdot 0=0.\end{split}\]
\end{document}
```

The two outputs are:

[image]
and
[image]

### For the users: see please the comments below.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle reading your link, it honestly looks like it's the same. But I currently do not know what action to take to have a good spacing even though I read the answer. Is there anything to insert in the preamble to have a correct spacing?

Comment: follow the link to that duplicate and see Werner's answer you can set \thickmuskip (the space around = and < ) to smaller values as he shows there

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So to have less spacing I have to insert each time \begingroup
\setlength{\thickmuskip}{0mu}
........
\endgroup or \begingroup
\setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu}
........
\endgroup or with \setlength{\thickmuskip}{0mu}...:-(? I was thinking of a macro or a package that would fix everything in one compilation for the whole document.

Comment: Some of these spaces are explicit, entered with `\,`.  Those should be examined to see if they are really intended.

Comment: Really, I see no overspacing, apart from the space explicitly inserted with `\,`. Note that if you use the (horrible) French notation for intervals, it should be `\mathopen]a,b\mathclose[`

Comment: @egreg too slow:-)

Comment: @egreg Have you read the thought of David :-)?

Comment: @Sebastiano no! do not set it each time. If you change the settings (and I see no reaon to change them) then it should be done globally in the document preamble so they are consistent.

Comment: @Sebastiano no we just looked at the output image that you posted, it is clear that the markup is wrong even if you hadn't posted a test document (although the test document  was good to conform that)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle (egreg) So I'm leaving everything as it is? Without actions? If the answer is yes I delete my question.

Comment: @Sebastiano no there are lots of actions, as the answer shows if you fix your markup the spacing will be better (and generally more even, if not smaller).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you please edit your answer, following my MWE, to get a better spacing, so I better understand your comment (there are so many actions) on how I should fix my preamble?

Comment: basically just remove all the `\,` and change every `]a,b[` to `\mathopen]a,b\mathclose[`. also use `\frac` not `\dfrac`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But egreg doesn't like it (horrible french notation)

Comment: egreg doesn't like pineapple pizza either. There is no hope for him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general question in the title is a duplicate of

[How to get less spacing in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41913/how-to-get-less-spacing-in-math-mode)

But much of the bad spacing is not due to the general settings but to bad markup, consider for example:

[image]

You need to mark `]` as a mathopen if you use it as an open delimiter

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


 $x\in ]a, b[$ % bad

 $x\in \mathopen]a, b\mathclose[$ % better

\end{document}
```

Similarly `y'\,f_{yy'}` the `\,` is doing nothing but force a bad space, just use `y' f_{yy'}`

Comment: Even though you got the tick in his self-answer OP thanks egreg :)

Comment: See also the `interval` package for typesetting `],a,b[` in a simpler fashion.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wouldn't it be better to use `x\in \mathopen]a, b\mathclose[` instead of `x\in \mathopen{]}a, b\mathclose{[}`? (The same thing as in [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407077/227621) to another question)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the great user @egreg takes from the chat and it is very important for me. Thank you very much @egreg.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm,
            left=3.2cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=10pt,
            a4paper]{geometry}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\newcommand{\tder}[2]{\frac{\diff #1}{\diff #2}}
\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\newcommand{\iv}[3][c]{%
  \csname iv@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iv@gen}[4]{#1#3,#4#2}
\newcommand{\iv@c}{\iv@gen{[}{]}} \let\iv@cc\iv@c
\newcommand{\iv@o}{\iv@gen{\mathopen]}{\mathclose[}} \let\iv@oo\iv@o
\newcommand{\iv@co}{\iv@gen{[}{\mathclose[}}
\newcommand{\iv@oc}{\iv@gen{\mathopen]}{]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Ovviamente deve essere $1-c^2>0$ e cioè $|c|<1$ perchè sia lecita la relazione \ldots. 
La costante arbitraria $c$ può avere segno qualsiasi; deve aversi cioè per ogni 
$x\in \iv[o]{a}{b}$, $y'(x)=c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ oppure $y'(x)=-c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$. 
Potrebbe essere $c=0$ compatibile solo con $y(a) = y(b)$, segmento parallelo all'asse~$x$. 
Se $c\ne 0$, allora anche $c/\sqrt{1-c^2}\ne 0$, e dovendo $y'$ essere continua non può 
accadere che per certi $x\in\iv[o]{a}{b}$ valga il segno $+$ e per altri il segno $-$ 
(altrimenti $y'$ salterebbe senza assumere i valori intermedi fra $c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ e 
$-c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$). Deve quindi valere $y'(x)=c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ per ogni $x\in]a,b[$, 
oppure $y'(x)=-c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ sempre per ogni $x\in]a,b[$: dato che $c$ è, 
come detto prima, costante di integrazione indeterminata, non si perde nulla a 
scrivere $y'(x)=c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ qualunque sia $c$. Posto $m=c/\sqrt{1-c^2}\in \mathbb{R}$, 
ed essendo $c$ variabile in $\iv[o]{-1}{1}$ allora $m=c/\sqrt{1-c^2}$ assumerà tutti 
i valori reali. La soluzione generale dell'equazione di Eulero è $y(x)=mx+k$; dovendo 
essere $y(a)=\alpha$ ed $y(b)=\beta$ si ricava $ma+k=\alpha$ ed $mb+k=\beta$, da cui 
$m=(\beta-\alpha)/(b-a)$ e $k=\alpha-a(\beta-\alpha)/(b-a)$. Ma ci si poteva fermare 
una volta scoperto che $y'$ deve essere costante: questo prova che le uniche soluzioni 
sono segmenti di rette come il percorso più breve, e ce n'è uno solo che passa per due 
punti dati $(a,\alpha)$ e $(b,\beta)$, come ben sappiamo. La funzione integranda non 
dipende esplicitamente da $x$ quindi il funzionale è del tipo
\[
\mathscr{F}(y)=\int_{a}^{b}f(y,y')\diff x
\]
In questo caso l'equazione di Eulero-Lagrange  
\[
\tder{}{x} \pder{f(y,y')}{y'}-\pder{f(y,y')}{y}=0
\]
Se poi $y$ è di classe $\mathcal{C}^2$ in $[a,b]$ diventa, dalla \eqref{elfd2}, per 
il teorema di derivazione delle funzioni composte,
\begin{equation}\label{edex}
f_{y}(y,y')-f_{y'y}(y,y')y'-f_{y'y'}(y,y')y''=0
\end{equation}
Moltiplicando la \eqref{edex} per $y'$, otteniamo l'equazione di Eulero-Lagrange è
\[
\tder{}{x}(f-y'\,f_{y'})=0.\]
Infatti si ha
\[
\begin{split}
\tder{}{x}(f-y'f_{y'})
  &= f_y\,y'+f_{y'}y''-y''f_{y'}-(y')^2f_{yy'}-y'y''f_{y'y'} \\
  &= y'(f_y-y'f_{yy'}-y''f_{y'y'})=y'\cdot 0=0.
\end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```